# Constructing or locating a point in a triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles, geometric-construction

Construct a point O in $\Delta ABC$ such that $OA+OC+OB$ value is minimum. Given that it is acute angled.

---

I think $OA=OB=OC$ is the case where we get it's minimum value. But i don't know how to find and locate the point. Please help me with this.

Comment: It's not the circumcentre, it's called the Fermat point. See for example Wolfram Math World:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatPoints.html
Or Wikipedia, but their article looks a bit heavy.

Comment: I'm not sure that equal segments would work because two equal 'diagonals' coming from the short-edge vertices  plus one equal 'straight' line from the other vertex could be longer than if the two 'diagonals' were kept nearer the shortest 'edge' of the triangle. My best guess is to either locate the point in the middle of the shortest edge or to bisect all the angles and locate the point at their intersection.